# Cannot read property 'getEvents' of null -> When non-owner of calendar tries to delete event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've got a google script associated with a spreadsheet that modifies a number of google calendars for different people. I'm the owner of each of those calendars and then they are shared with individual people. I have one person that will manage this sheet and every calendar is shared with them.

When i run the script to update a given month of calendars the below code runs without issue. When the non-owner attempts to run the same code they get the below error code.

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of null at UpdateCalendar(Code:209:31)"
```

Line 209 refers to:

```
var events = CallCalendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate); //create array of events of full month for given calendar
```

The full section of code is below:

```
//Cycle through each Calendar and delete the events
  for (var x = 0; x < CallCalendars.length; x++) {//Cycle through each Different calendar
    var CallCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CallCalendars[x].ID); //Get ID of each Calendar
    var events = CallCalendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate); //create array of events of full month for given calendar
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){ //Cycle across array of full month of events to delete each one
      var ev = events[i]; //instantiate each event
      Logger.log("ev.getTitle(): " + ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
      ev.deleteEvent(); //Delete instantiated event
    }
  }
```

I'm presuming this is an issue with permissions in some way. I'd really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: The code is silently failing at `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CallCalendars[x].ID)`. Where does `CallCalendars` come from?

Comment: Sorry CallCalendars is an array of Objects that includes a persons name at CallCalendars[x].Name and the ID of their calendar at CallCalendar[x].ID.

Comment: Did you verify that the non-owner has access to that array?

Comment: @ Diego - That array is defined above in code.

Comment: I think you'll need to do some debugging with that user. If they have access to the IDs, but `CalendarApp.getCalendarById()` returns `null`, then that means they don't have access to the calendars.

Comment: Sigh... After getting access to their account it was obvious. I had given them access but they hadn't clicked on the links in the email to accept access and therefore it hadn't been added to their google calendar. Once they added it they had the required permissions. Thanks for the help but sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation / Issue:

It looks you are passing some **wrong** calendar `IDs` or `IDs` you **don't have permission** to access.

- One workaround would be to use a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement so
  whenever your code comes across with these `IDs` to `continue` with the
  next iteration.

### Solution:

```
//Cycle through each Calendar and delete the events
  for (var x = 0; x < CallCalendars.length; x++) {//Cycle through each Different calendar
    var CallCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CallCalendars[x].ID); //Get ID of each Calendar
    try{
    var events = CallCalendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate); //create array of events of full month for given calendar
    }
    catch(e){continue;}
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){ //Cycle across array of full month of events to delete each one
      var ev = events[i]; //instantiate each event
      Logger.log("ev.getTitle(): " + ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
      ev.deleteEvent(); //Delete instantiated event
    }
  }
```

Comment: While this worked to bypass the error, it simply bypassed every calendar. The issue has been solved in the above comments and was related to permissions. Thank you for responding.